# Конкретная последовательность чисел при генерации первого случайного числа srand

Tags: c++, c, случайные-числа

Почему-то генерируются *не совсем случайные* числа.

Код (каждый раз новый запуск программы):

```
 srand(time(0));
 int i = rand()+10000;
```

Числа:

- 32860
- 32925
- 32951
- 32984
- 33017

Почему?

Comment: Потому что такой генератор. Он генерирует псевдослучайные числа.

Comment: Вы весь код приведите... может, вы перед каждым `rand()` вызываете `srand()` :)

Comment: @Harry, да) А что надо один раз?

Comment: Ты смотри, сразу в точку :) Конечно. Вы же его тем самым заставляете генерировать НЕ случайные числа, а СЛЕДУЮЩЕЕ псевдослучайное число после указанного вами. ОДИН РАЗ где-нибудь в начале `main`, и больше не трогайте.

Comment: @Harry, оставил один вызов, всё равно такие же результаты, только уже 34 тысячи. Я так понял оно увеличивается из-за того time идёт?

Comment: Еще раз - дайте код, pls. Вот https://ideone.com/aQHZNM - все работает; тут просто размах RAND_MAX пошире.

Comment: @Harry, ну тут очень много. Есть класс. В конструкторе должен генерироваться уникальный айди объекта. Использую для этого `rand()`. Объектов сейчас создаётся 2. Пары айди полученные `rand()` (без +10000 и чего-либо другого) странные: первое всегда 27 тыс. и возрастает, а второе всегда меньше первого и более-менее случайное .

Comment: Что-то тут не так... но понять, что, заочно точно не могу.

Comment: @Harry, `>второе всегда меньше первого`. Ну ладно, не всегда. Но первое определённо не случайное, зависит от `time`

Comment: @АртурКлочко а если у вас на компьютере создать простенькую программу и взять код из примера Harry, то какой будет результат?

Comment: Внятнее сформулируйте вопрос. Пока что не ясно о чем именно идет речь: 1) о первом вызове `rand()` при каждом отдельном запуске программы или 2) о множественных вызовах `rand()` в рамках одного запуска.

Comment: @Harry: Дело совершено не в этом. У него `srand()` и так вызывается один раз. Но при этом и `rand()` вызывается один раз (буквально так, как написано выше).

Comment: @AnT, написал же - `rand()` вызывается дважды при запуске программы.

Answer (score 3):

Согласно вашему описанию, дело в том, что в вашей реализации первое значение `rand()` коррелирует с seed-значением, использованным в `srand()`, таким образом, что возрастание seed приводит к возрастанию первого результата `rand()`. В результате нарастающее значение времени, возвращаемое `time(0)`, приводит к росту первого результата `rand()`.

Можно попробовать делать один-два "холостых" вызова `rand()` сразу после `srand(time(0))`. Это должно устранить наблюдаемый эффект.

Но в общем и целом такое поведение `srand()/rand()` не является чем-то из ряда вон выходящим или ошибочным. Это никоим образом не мешает использовать `rand()` для тех целей, для которых такие функции предназначаются.

Comment: [Пример](http://rextester.com/VNI13954), подтверждающий ваш ответ.

Comment: `>делать один-два "холостых" вызова` - Да я уже так и сделал. Странно, вроде раньше такого не наблюдал.